# Какая привязка WCF подойдет?

Tags: c#, binding, wcf

Пишу информационную систему с использованием WCF-технологии. Подразумевается, что на одном компьютере (сервере) будет находится база данных, запросы к которой будудт обрабатываться на ней же. Для этого есть приложение, которое будет устанавливаться на компах локальной сети. В таком случае мне должен подойти netTcpBinding. Но у меня еще есть приложение ASP.NET, которое тоже должно посылать запросы на сервер и получать ответ. Тогда вроде как мне надо wsHttpBinding. Какую привязку мне лучше выбрать, чтобы реализовать и тот и тот вариант подключения к серверу одновременно?

Answer (score 1):

`WCF` позволяет устанавливать несколько привязок на разных адресах.

Но я вам всё же советую не заморачиваться и везде использовать `wsHttpBinding`.

Comment: @Veikedo, а данная привязка позволит передавать данные с одного компа на другой в сети? Мне просто не попадалось, как наладить работу WCF в реальной сети

Comment: Да, подойдёт

Comment: www.wcftutorial.net

Хороший справочный ресурс по wcf